# Is it possible to check for bad sectors (read error) for a disk with unknown partitions?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, bad-sectors, disk-utility

Windows shows that the partition style is GPT, but of course, it does not recognise the partitions because it has Linux partitions. In this case, can I check the disk for physical read errors? I mean the read command failing due to hardware problems, not software issues like corrupt partition, etc.

If so how? All I know is that the disk name in Disk Management is "Disk 2", it does not have any drive name/ID.If it is not possible, must I use a Linux computer?

Comment: Start by getting something to read the S.M.A.R.T info from the drive - Crystal Disk Info for Windows or Smaetmontools for  Linux for example.

Comment: If you want to check **physical disk** for bad sectors then the type (and even the presence) of the partitions makes no sense. Check it as physical device - and all sectors (service sectors, sectors in all partitions, of known and unknown type, unused space sectors between partitions) will be checked.

Comment: davidgo, smartmontools runs under Windows as well. Furthermore you can redirect it's output in a file showing decimal figures - this is the software I would prefer. The only advantage is the lack of automatic USB bridge recognition in case of external devices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use ddrescue for this purpose. Copy into the Null-Device and use a log file.
ddrescue knows how to handle read errors!

The log file will finally list all unreadable areas on the source drive in absolute addresses. You just have to divide them by the numbers of bytes per sector to arrive at the sector number.

I am not aware of a similar tool for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Various third-party disk diagnostics programs should be able to do this, as they can simply access the raw "block device" and don't really need the filesystem to get involved in the first place. I can't offer any names (I'd probably use Linux ddrescueview) but I'm sure there are plenty.

Windows *does* recognize the partitions, in that it knows exactly where they begin and end; it only doesn't recognize their *contents,* and that's an important distinction in this case. Even though the Linux partitions don't have a recognizable filesystem, they can still be accessed as "raw" disks through their device-names.

Much like Linux has `/dev/sd*` for accessing raw disks, `\\.\Device\Harddisk*\Partition*` is the exact Windows equivalent that any program with Admin rights can read/write, for performing tasks like cloning the whole disk (or individual partitions), updating the boot sector, etc.

("Disk 2" in the Volume Manager probably corresponds to `Harddisk2` in the device namespace, and the whole disk is represented by `Harddisk<x>\Partition0` or `Harddisk<x>\DR<x>`.)